# Can we use aggregate function on both sides of having

Tags: sql

Pretty simple question - can we run something like the following in sql, if not what's an alternative :

Edit #1 fixed question

The following query should answer : Give me all names and salaries by month for folks whose salary is greater than average of all salaries(not greater than avg. salary by month)

Select name, month, salary
From table
Group by 1,2
Having sum(salary) > avg(salary)

Comment: If you remove `salary` from the select clause, then your query is perfectly valid, assuming that logic is what you really want.

Comment: It depends which value of `salary` you wish to generate for each row/group in the result.  You could also change the `SELECT` list to: `SELECT name, month, AVG(salary) ...`.  What was your actual requirement?

Comment: You have changed your request a lot. The answer to your original question is a simple yes. Now it shows that you want something completely different. Make it a habit to always explain what you want to do instead of showing us some query of which you hope we'll get what it is supposed to do. Then, when askling SQL questions always tag them with your DBMS. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You want two different aggregations:

- The sum per name and month
- The average per month

One option is using two CTEs:

```
with m as (select month, avg(salary) as sal from mytable group by month)
, nm as (select name, month, sum(salary) as sal from mytable group by name, month)
select m.month, m.sal as avgsal, nm.name, nm.sal
from nm
join m on m.month = nm.month
where nm.sal > m.sal
order by m.month, nm.name
```

Answer (score -1):

The following might do what you want.

```sql
WITH
TABLE_GROUPED AS (
  SELECT name, month, avg(salary) avg_salary, sum(salary) sum_salary
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
  GROUP BY 1, 2
)
SELECT *
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE sum_salary > avg_salary
```

However, I am not sure why would you want to do that. Considering that the `salary` is positive, the only filtered grouped rows would be the ones that contain only one element. If the group has more than one element, the sum will always be higher than the mean.